# Writing a program that estimates math constant e without using any functions

Tags: python

Write a program that estimates the value of the mathematical constant e by using the formula
[Note: Your program can stop after summing 10 terms.]

e = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ...

I am new to programming languages and trying to learn python by myself. This question has been asked and answered before but I am seeking a solution without any function or module and I want to use only while or for loop.

Edit: This is the code that I wrote for calculating a factorial:

```
n = 0
factorial = 1
n = raw_input( "Enter a positive integer: ")
n = int(n)
while n < 0:
    print "Enter a POSITIVE integer: "
backup = n
backup = int(backup)
while n != 0:
    factorial *= n
    n -= 1
print "%d!= %d" % (backup, factorial)
```

And this could be funny to most of you but this is the code that I wrote for the question but it ended up with a syntax error:

```
accuracy = 1
factorial = 1
counter = 1
e = 1.0

accuracy = raw_input( "Enter desired accuracy of e: ")
accuracy = int (accuracy)

while (counter <= (accuracy - 1))
    factorial = factorial * counter
    e = e + ( 1 / float(factorial))
    counter += 1

print "Constant e is: ", e
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could show your efforts, this is not a code-for-free! service.

Comment: If you already have the formula why is causing you a problem? How to do factorial in python?

Comment: Then investigate the syntax error... Line `while...` should end with `:`.

Comment: @Benjamin That was quite shameful to me, thank you very much. It is working.

Comment: @UgurErangin, no shame in it. With experience you learn how to follow the traceback messages and errors...

Comment: that's why it's important to show your code and the exact error message in Stack Overflow, this way you 1) will get much less downvotes, 2) you will help everyone (including yourself) to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is writing a factorial function. This can be done recursively or with a for-loop:

```
def factorial(n):
    return 1 if n < 2 else n * factorial(n-1)
```

or:

```
def factorial(n):
    x = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        x *= i
    return x
```

and then for calculating `e` we can again use recursion or a for-loop. This function takes a parameter which indicates how many terms in the formula it should evaluate (so you should call with `10` in your case).

```
def calc_e(t):
    if not t:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 / factorial(t-1) + calc_e(t-1)
```

or:

```
def calc_e(t):
   s = 0
   for i in range(t):
       s += 1 / factorial(i)
   return s
```

and they both work:

```
>>> calc_e(1)
1.0
>>> calc_e(2)
2.0
>>> calc_e(3)
2.5
>>> calc_e(4)
2.6666666666666665
>>> calc_e(5)
2.708333333333333
>>> calc_e(10)
2.7182815255731922
>>> calc_e(20)
2.7182818284590455
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation in detail.

Comment: Why create your on factorial function where their already one in the math module? [factorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.factorial). It 's faster than a one written in python.

Comment: @YassineFaris Because it is good practice to understand things fully, the OP didn't want to use functions and if your using the math module then you may as well use `math.e` :p

Comment: @UgurErangin Please accept (grey --> green tick) then :)